# GORM using foreign key instead of domain object

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Say I have a Domain Object `User` which contains an `Organization` field. I can map that using a foreign key and let hibernate take care of the rest like so:

```
class User {

    String id
    String firstName
    Organization organization

    static mapping = {
        table 'user'
        id column: "user_id", generator:'assigned'
        organization column: 'organization_Id'
    }
}

class Organization {

    String id
    String name
    String address

    static mapping = {
        table 'organization'
        id column: "organization_id", generator:'assigned'
    }
}
```

This works fine, but when I want to query for all users in an organization I might have to do something like this

```
String orgId = "some id"
Organization org = Organization.findById(orgId)
List<User> users = User.findAllByOrganization(org)
```

It would be convenient to not have to  pass the `Organization` domain object and instead just pass the Organization.Id which is the foreign key on the `User` table.

How I want my code to look is the following:

```
String orgId = "some id"
List<User> users = User.findAllByOrganization(orgId)
```

After researching, it seems like this is not possible, I need to first query for the `Organization` and then use that object. Is there a way I am unaware of?

Answer (score 5):

One way I like to do it is to use a proxy of your domain object instead of a hydrated instance of it. You can use [`load()`](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/load.html) to obtain the proxy. This means no database call is made as long as you don't access any of the domain object's properties beyond the `id`.

```
def users = Users.findByOrganization(Organization.load(orgId))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Criteria`](https://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html):

```java
String orgId = "some id"

List<User> users = User.createCriteria().list {
    organization {
      idEq(orgId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options there:

1. add a redundant `orgId` field to you `User` class and use it for the
   lookup.
2. Use a fake object for your lookup:

.

```
Organization org = new Organization()
org.id = 'someId' // looks strange, but you can not use id inside constructor
def users = Users.findAllByOrganization org
```